# Kotlin: Check for Null and Assign?

Tags: kotlin

```
var something: Something? = null
val notNull: Something = ...

...

fun getSomething() {
    something = something ?: notNull
    return something
}
```

Is there in Kotlin any way to do both `something = something ?: notNull; return something` at the same time?

Or.. even better, is there a way to do it with generics in an inline function?

Comment: yes I think. any error?

Comment: Assignments can't return, probably wanna do with `let()` but it will look worse than this... IMO this is best way to do this, this one is properly readable as well.

Comment: Depending on your exact use case maybe `val something by lazy { notNull }` and that can just be public instead of `getSomething`

Comment: `return something ?: notNull.also { something = it }`

Comment: @IR42 that should be an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fun getSomething(): Something {
    return something ?: notNull.also { something = it }
}
// or 
fun getSomething(): Something = something ?: notNull.also { something = it }
```